# Linear Transformation on Permutation Set

Tags: permutations, linear-transformations, nilpotence, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and ${v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$ be a basis of $V$. Let $\sigma \in S_n$ and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformation defined by $T(v_i)=v_\sigma(i)$. Then what can you say about $T$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Null space of $T$ consists of the $0$ vector!
Also the matrix of the linear transformation with respect to this basis consists of only $0$'s and $1$'s and has $n$ linearly independent rows and columns.